# how to deploy vb.net project to client with crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Built of vb.net project is completed and I want to deploy my project to the user but when I deployed, the user can't view the report. It shows an error 'invalid directory'.

How to solve it?

This is an error when we view the crystal report.

[image: this is an error when we view the crystal report]

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your post and show the actual error message as text instead of a screenshot? Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: have you configured it in app.config